# -Wextra works in shell but not in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I was using today a bash script to perform some things that I need to execute a code, and I encountered with the error in the title. In the bash script, the shell says -Wextra command not found, but if I execute the command by myself:`mpicc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o ptmm PerfTestMM.c -lblas` it actually works. So I was wondering, why this could be caused? In the shell and in the bash script the very same command was run:

```
CC=mpicc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -pedantic
CFILE=PerfTestMM.c
EXE=ptmm
$($CC $CFLAGS -o $EXE $CFILE -lblas)
```

Comment: `CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'` Without the quotes you’re trying to run _a command_ called `-Wextra` (hence `-Wextra command not found`, that error is actually from the `CFLAGS=…` line).

Comment: Why are you running the command with `$()`? Does it really print something that you then want to execute?

Comment: See also: [BashFAQ/050 — I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @Biffen Hi, thanks! I am correcting that right now. It is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Biffen for the answer, CFLAGS=... has to be CFLAGS='...'.